# Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it is extremely slow, painfully so

Tags: 14.04, video, performance

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit, as that was recommended for 2gb or RAM or less) on a Acer Veriton N281G D425 Intel Atom 1.8GHz 2GB RAM and a 500GB HDD. This is a small box computer that I got surplus for a "song" and want to use it for my son (5 yrs old).  I had played with Linux years and years ago (like 10 - 15 yrs - Mandrake, Lindows, and Suse ~ but I was just playing).  Anyhow I first put on Qimo 2.0 and it ran like a high end machine but as you power users know Qimo is build on top of Ubuntu 10 or thereabouts and it's no longer supported.  So I went to Ubuntu thinking I'd just download the kids progs that my son took a liking to.  After all a lot more room for him to grow with the OS with a current version of Ubuntu.
Well, it is running horrible.  Especially video responsiveness. It's painful. Remember when Windows 95 first came out, MS claimed it would run on a 386 - this is like that, but worse. 
What did I do wrong or more importantly can I fix this issue?
Thanks,
Bill

Comment: That laptop is not really up to running Ubuntu, the specs for the basic Ubuntu desktop (Unity) are about as high as they come, you should look at Xubuntu or Lubuntu, same OS different Desktop http://xubuntu.org/ or http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback Mark!  While I was waiting for answers I did some Googling and found that there was a vendor selling these units refurbished with something called "Linux Linpus" pre-loaded.  Ever heard of that one?  Is it worth looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ubuntu 10 ran top notch, take a look at [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/), which is more like ubuntu 10, [Ubuntustudio](http://ubuntustudio.org/), which also uses the same desktop but includes a lowlatency kernel, or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), which uses openbox.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback "mchid"!  While I was waiting for answers I did some Googling and found that there was a vendor selling these units refurbished with something called "Linux Linpus" pre-loaded.  Ever heard of that one?  Is it worth looking at?

Comment: I don't know. maybe check http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You said ubuntu 10 ran great. Xubuntu, Ubuntustudio, or Lubuntu should run just as good if not better. Also, redhat (linpus is fedora based as far as I know) doesn't have the repo that debian has (not even sure if they have any kids applications).

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, Ubuntu 10 ran great.  So forgive a noobie question but when you say "repo" do you mean that place where you can download gobs of software for Ubuntu?  Does each Linux distro have its own "area" like that or are there certain core parts of a distro that allow clustering by the "root" (Debian, Fedora, ect al.....)  Is there a place I can look at the distro area of these different flavors of Linux?  I want to use the flavor that has the most choices for the little guy. :)  Darn, wish someone was still updating Qimo.... but such is life. :)

Comment: Yes, repo is the repository of software available from the distro. ubuntu is debian based and debian has the largest repo by far. Having ubuntu, you have access to all the debian stuff and more. This page shows that Debian/Ubuntu has twice as many available packages compared to Fedora. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#Package_management_and_installation

Comment: Thanks again mchid.  I think I'm going to give Ubuntustudio a whirl and see how it goes.

Comment: @BillBrockmiller if this answers your question, don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the icon to the left to mark it as solved. thanks!

Comment: Well, here I am, a few days later with my Acer Veriton N281G D425 Intel Atom 1.8GHz 2GB RAM and 500GB HDD. Tried the following distributions, none with good results:
- Ubuntu Studio - still so slow, painfully so
- Lubuntu 32 bit 15.04 - would install completely, but on first reboot it would hang at a white screen.  I tried twice, two complete fresh reinstalls, both with the same tragic result
- Xubuntu - install crapped out (I think I am going to try Xubuntu one more time, but not feeling it ...)

Comment: ............these should work given the fact that Qimo 2.0 (built on top of Ubuntu 10) works VERY well. But they are not.

Well, since I've got a 500 GB hard drive I put Qimo back on and I'll give it part of the drive to play in, my son likes the stuff that comes with it.  But I want to put something else on the bulk of the drive.  Assuming Xubuntu fails again, what's next?  I read a bit about "puppy" for slower machines.  Is there anything there?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @BillBrockmiller yes, there is debian: https://www.debian.org/, antixos (built on debian): http://antix.mepis.org/index.php?title=Main_Page, there is crunchbang: http://crunchbang.org/download/ (development has ended, however, you can still install it and upgrade the system to the current debian (from wheezy to jessie). Also, your results are strange what did you set for swappiness (how big was your swap partition)? Did you disable swappiness (this would be a bad mistake and would cripple performance).

Comment: @BillBrockmiller I had lubuntu running on an old pentium4 machine we bought over 10 years ago that originally ran XP. The machine couldn't handle the standard  Ubuntu desktop. Later, I installed Debian and I had Gnome shell running faster than LXDE did on lubuntu. Another machine wouldn't even install a standard linux desktop. This computer originally ran windows 98. I used antixos to install and to my surprise it actually worked. Both crunchbang and antixos are based on debian so they both have all the same software available. I personally like(d) crunchbang but it's more for power users.

Comment: @BillBrockmiller I don't know how well it will run but http://www.doudoulinux.org/web/english/index.html is based on debian and the edubuntu website has a lot of info http://edubuntu.org/other-educational-systems. Also, qimo was based on xfce so maybe try xfce for debian and see how that works out. They are currently working on Debian jr  for kids https://wiki.debian.org/DebianJr

Comment: Thanks again Mchid!  I'm going to keep an eye on Debian Jr for certain. I took your advice about xfce/Debian and loaded the xfce/Debian version of Mint and it works like a charm and now have a dual boot with Qimo and Linux Mint. Any insight on Mint? Their site claimed low resource needs and with your advice I gave the xfce flavor of Mint a shot (32bit)

Comment: @BillBrockmiller another thing I recently thought about: You can disable the framebuffer in xfce and ubuntustudio to get better performance. This also applies to xfce from debain and may be the culprit   for the decline in performance compared to version 10. I think the setting is under display, graphics, windo management or extras, I'll have to check.

Comment: @BillBrockmiller okay, it's actually the "composter" and it can make a big difference especially when graphics resources are limited. Go to the "settings manager" and click on "window manager tweaks" then, untik the box for "enable display composting".